# pg_stats_activity.datname is null on one record

Tags: postgresql, postgres-12

i'am using this query to determite hit/read value for my databases

```
SELECT 
  datname, 
  CASE 
    WHEN blks_read = 0 THEN 0 
    ELSE blks_hit / blks_read 
  END AS ratio 
FROM 
  pg_stat_database;
  
 select * from pg_stat_database;
```

i have results, but the first column datname is NULL, and it has worst ratio

user: postgres

```
datname     |ratio  |
------------+-------+
NULL        |9984265|
template1   |      0|
template0   |      0|
postgres    |      9|
db1         |   2078|
db2         |    660|
```

what does the null mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-DATABASE-VIEW), `pg_stat_databases` contains a record for objects that are shared with multiple databases:

It has a `datid` = 0 ..

> OID of this database, or 0 for objects belonging to a shared relation

.. and has no `datname`:

> Name of this database, or NULL for the shared objects.

Comment: You were 20 seconds faster;) Your link is correct, but your quote refers to OID insted of datname.

Comment: @Steeeve 20 sec. means a lot in SO :-D The quote is the description of the column `datid` in the link I provided, as referred to `datid`. But you're right, it might be confusing. I just edited my answer. Thanks for the hint

Comment: so as i can see, this might be an internal tables of postgres. A i right?

Comment: @Drilla exactly, this is a postgres internal view. cheers

Comment: @JimJones is there any way to reduce ratio for it?

Comment: @Drilla possibly yes, but this would need a much better description of your cluster... and you'd need to ask another question with more details.